# How to display text in pygame?

Tags: python, text, pygame

I can't figure out to display text in pygame.
I know I can't use print like in regular Python IDLE but I don't know how.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

BLACK = ( 0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = ( 255, 0, 0)

pygame.init()
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('P.Earth')
while 1: # main game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:           
            pygame.display.update() 

import time

direction = ''
print('Welcome to Earth')
pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, [55,500,10,5], 0)
time.sleep(1)
```

This is only the beginning part of the whole program.
If there is a format that will allow me to show the text I type in the pygame window that'd be great. So instead of using print I would use something else. But I don't know what that something else is.
When I run my program in pygame it doesn't show anything.
I want the program to run in the pygame window instead of it just running in idle.

Answer (score 83):

You can create a surface with text on it. For this take a look at this short example:

```
pygame.font.init() # you have to call this at the start, 
                   # if you want to use this module.
my_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 30)
```

This creates a new object on which you can call the `render` method.

```
text_surface = my_font.render('Some Text', False, (0, 0, 0))
```

This creates a new surface with text already drawn onto it.
At the end you can just blit the text surface onto your main screen.

```
screen.blit(text_surface, (0,0))
```

Bear in mind, that every time the text changes, you have to recreate the surface again, to see the new text.

Comment: If you've already called `pygame.init()` in your program, you don't have to call `pygame.font.init()` as well. There's also [`pygame.font.Font`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font) if you want to load the font from a file in your game directory.

Comment: If you're on a recent pygame version, use the `freetype` module instead of the `font` module. It's better in every way.

Comment: Better use the following to get red text because default background is black and then you can not see anything:

textsurface = myfont.render('Some Text', False, (220, 0, 0))

Answer (score 20):

There's also the [`pygame.freetype`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html) module which is more modern, works with more fonts and offers additional functionality.

Create a font object with [`pygame.freetype.SysFont()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.SysFont) or [`pygame.freetype.Font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font%60) if the font is inside of your game directory.

You can render the text either with the [`render`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font.render) method similarly to the old `pygame.font.Font.render` or directly onto the target surface with [`render_to`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font.render_to).

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype  # Import the freetype module.


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
GAME_FONT = pygame.freetype.Font("your_font.ttf", 24)
running =  True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    # You can use `render` and then blit the text surface ...
    text_surface, rect = GAME_FONT.render("Hello World!", (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(text_surface, (40, 250))
    # or just `render_to` the target surface.
    GAME_FONT.render_to(screen, (40, 350), "Hello World!", (0, 0, 0))

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You are missing argument for antialias and return is not a tuple: `Font.render(text, antialias, color, background=None): return Surface`

Answer (score 9):

When displaying I sometimes make a new file called Funk. This will have the font, size etc. This is the code for the class:

```
import pygame

def text_to_screen(screen, text, x, y, size = 50,
            color = (200, 000, 000), font_type = 'data/fonts/orecrusherexpand.ttf'):
    try:

        text = str(text)
        font = pygame.font.Font(font_type, size)
        text = font.render(text, True, color)
        screen.blit(text, (x, y))

    except Exception, e:
        print 'Font Error, saw it coming'
        raise e
```

Then when that has been imported when I want to display text taht updates E.G score I do:

```
Funk.text_to_screen(screen, 'Text {0}'.format(score), xpos, ypos)
```

If it is just normal text that isn't being updated:

```
Funk.text_to_screen(screen, 'Text', xpos, ypos)
```

You may notice {0} on the first example. That is because when .format(whatever) is used that is what will be updated. If you have something like Score then target score you'd do {0} for score then {1} for target score then .format(score, targetscore)

Answer (score 7):

This is slighly more OS independent way:

```
# do this init somewhere
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
font = pygame.font.Font(pygame.font.get_default_font(), 36)

# now print the text
text_surface = font.render('Hello world', antialias=True, color=(0, 0, 0))
screen.blit(text_surface, dest=(0,0))
```